# $_FILES is empty but move_uploaded_file() works

Tags: php, file-upload

I have the next code:

```
<?php
if(empty($_FILES)) 
    echo 'vacia'; 
else 
    echo 'con algo';
var_dump($_FILES);

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "./" . $fileName);
?>
```

Now, empty($_FILES) is true because shows me the string 'vacia'. Also show me 'array(0) {}' in var_dump().

But move_uploaded_file() still works perfectly. Could someone explain me that?

the error_reporting(E_ALL) say 'Undefined index Filedata' in each line where I use it, but I can understand why move_uploaded_file() still works :/

Comment: Does your form have post method including the right enctype? Show your HTML form.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php tag error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- POST is default. You told me that a few days ago. She would just need to make sure it isn't expressly GET :p

Comment: @Adelphia That should be "POST should be default" lol if a post method isn't included, then form defaults to GET.

Comment: @alex how did you determine that it "works perfectly"?

Comment: @Fred-ii- ooooh, that's what it was. i always specify so i wouldn't know.

Comment: @Adelphia because I get a copy of the file that I choose next to my php file.

Comment: Would you please post your HTML form as I asked you 3 hours prior to this, so we can all leave the guesswork out of it. No one can answer this. Or read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php and fix it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should check the return of `move_uploaded_files()`:

```
$result = move_uploaded_files($tempFile, "./", $fileName);
```

It will be `true` on success or `false` on error. In your case, it should be `false`. Since the array indices do not exist, PHP will throw an E_NOTICE level error and use an empty string, so you're actually doing this:

```
move_uploaded_file('', "./", '');
```

But without E_NOTICE enabled, there will be no visible error message. (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Actually it's returning true D: what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check to see if the file exists instead. Just because the name exists doesn't mean the file exists.

```
if(is_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])){
    echo 'vacia'; 
}else{
    echo 'con algo';
    exit("File doesn't exist, I can't move it so I'm out!");
}
var_dump($_FILES);

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "./" . $fileName);
```

Comment: is_file() retun false no matter which file I choose but always  makes the upload.

Comment: What does your HTML Form look like?